# Disable save item button while save process is not completed

Tags: event-handlers, splistitem

User clicks on Save Button and saving procedure can take "few" seconds. User can click again..that`s why i need to disable save button, how can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

I would use the event handlers in JQuery to bind a disable for the ajax events.

http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax_Events